# How to use HTMX in large Vuejs project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, htmx

We are using **Vuejs** in our project, but I'm trying to implement **HTMX** in our view and I have no clue how. I know that I probably can't use HTMX in Vuejs and I can't change our whole project to HTMX right now.

I was thinking to use **v-html** and generate whole HTMX there but it doesn't work because when I import `import 'htmx.org';` based on [HTMX](https://htmx.org/docs/) doc, vue just hates it :D

Edit: While writing this question, we decided to do it as an separated project but I am curious anyway. Is is even possible? There is not much questions about HTMX yet, I didn't find anything helpful.
I am happy to answer any question for clarification.

Thanks and sorry for my potato english!

I tried to implement HTMX in our VueJs project for separated page or component and it didn't work.

Comment: Why would you mix both? Just import the cdn in the `index.html` file and you should be good to go